# Calculating value of checkboxes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I need to calculate the values of items in an HTML form using checkboxes.  Each checkbox is related to a product serial number, and each checkbox in the form has a different points value. I can't allow the sum of the values to be greater than a predetermined number.  I found this JavaScript, which calculates the sum, but when I use it in a form, I can't parse the actual item number. Instead, the form returns the value of a checkbox.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function chkcontrol(j) {
var sum=0;
for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){

if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
sum = sum + parseInt(document.form1.ckb[i].value);
}
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Sum :"+ sum;

if(sum >500){
sum = sum - parseInt(document.form1.ckb[j].value);
document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
alert("Sum of the selection can't be more than 500") 
//return false;
}
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Sum :"+ sum;
}
}
</script>
```

And the table looks like this:

```
<form name=form1 method=post action=check.php>

<table class='table table-striped'>
  
<tr><th>Select</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=120 onclick='chkcontrol(0)';> Serial# 123001 (value = 120) </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=200 onclick='chkcontrol(1)';> Serial# 123002 - (value = 200) </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=350 onclick='chkcontrol(2)';> Serial# 123003 - (value = 350) </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type=checkbox name=ckb value=100 onclick='chkcontrol(3)';> Serial# 123004 - (value = 100) </td></tr>
</table></form>
Sum of the values can't exceed 500. 
<br><br>
<div id=msg></div>
```

Currently, the value of the checkbox is the number that is added to the sum. When I parse the form, I can only get that number via the name cab and I don't get any information about the Serial#.  What I need is to be able to have the value of the checkbox be equal to a serial number of the item - i.e. 123004 - and I can later reference this serial number in a database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make a minimal, reproducible example. Currently, your code produces "`Cannot read property 'ckb' of undefined"`"

Comment: Sorry about that.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Your calculation part works fine . So , what you are not able to achieve ?

Comment: When I parse the web page, I can only get back the values of the numbers that are being added - as the JavaScript uses this value in the calculation.  I need to be able to include a serial number of the actual item - which is shown in the text of the checkbox.  For example, in the first checkbox, the value of 120 is the number that is added, while I need to be able to include "123001" as the serial number for that checkbox item to be processed by the form.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a data attribute for each of the checkbox and add the serial number. Then on execution of the function use document.querySelectorAll to get all the checked checkbox.
`document.querySelectorAll` will give a nodelist. To use the array method `map` it is first converted to array using spread operator `...`. Array method `map` is used here to return an array of the serial numbers which is retrieved from data attribute

```js
function chkcontrol(j) {
  var sum = 0;
  const checkedBoxes = []
  for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++) {

    if (document.form1.ckb[i].checked) {
      sum = sum + parseInt(document.form1.ckb[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Sum :" + sum;

    if (sum > 500) {
      sum = sum - parseInt(document.form1.ckb[j].value);
      document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false;
      alert("The total points used can't be more than 500")
      //return false;
    }
    remaining = 500 - sum;
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "<b>Points Used: </b>" + sum + "<br><b>Remaining Points: </b>" + remaining;

  }
  // added code here
  const box = [...document.querySelector('form[name="form1"]')
               .querySelectorAll('input[name="ckb"]:checked')]
               .map(item => item.dataset.serial);
  console.log(box)
}
```

```html
<form name='form1'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='ckb' data-serial='123001' value='120' onclick='chkcontrol(0)' ;> Serial# 123001 (value = 120) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='ckb' data-serial='123002' value='200' onclick='chkcontrol(1)' ;> Serial# 123002 - (value = 200) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='ckb' data-serial='123003' value='350' onclick='chkcontrol(2)' ;> Serial# 123003 - (value = 350) </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='ckb' data-serial='123004' value='100' onclick='chkcontrol(3)' ;> Serial# 123004 - (value = 100) </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<div id='msg'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but when I try and parse the form, I only get the value of "name" - and "data-serial" is not passed to the parsing script.  The buffer looks like this - &ckb=120&ckb=200 (after selecting the first two checkboxes)

Comment: Is it possible to have the value equal to the serial number and have the JavaScript use a different variable in the checkbox?  Or, would it be possible to have two values - the first being the number for the calculation, and the second being the serial number?  For example - "120-123001".  If I can get back "120-123001", I can parse the serial number out of it.  In other words - If I put "120-123001" as the value, can JavaScript parse the first number and use it in the calculation?

Comment: You need to add `data-serial` as a property to the input type checkbox. Look at the html code in the example

Comment: I did add it to the form: ``` <input type=checkbox name=ckb value=260 data-serial=111345 onclick='chkcontrol(0)' ;> ``` But the form doesn't pass along the value of data-serial.

Comment: Your should add quotes. Secondly you don't need to pass. the data serial. On execution of the function it will pick up by itself using document.querySelector. Also you need to wrap your entire html inside a `form` with name `form1`

Comment: I added quotes, but the parsing script from the form still is only returning the values - &ckb=220&ckb=110&ckb=150

Comment: This is an order form where the end user only gets X number of points to spend.  I need to pass the serial number to the parsing form so I know what they ordered.

Comment: I fixed it by adding this to the JavaScript  -

var numser = (document.form1.ckb[i].value)
var arr=numser.split("-");
sum = sum + parseInt(arr[0]);

Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 0):

will you try that... ?

```js
const 
  myForm = document.forms['my-forn']
  ckb_n  = ['ckb1', 'ckb2', 'ckb3', 'ckb4' ]
, pSum   = document.querySelector('#p-sum span')
  ;
  
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit for test
  }
myForm.oninput = e =>
  {
  let total = ckb_n.reduce((sum,nam)=>
    {
    sum += myForm[nam].checked ? Number(myForm[nam].value) : 0
    return sum
    }
    , 0)
  if (total > 500)
    {
    e.target.checked = false
    let label = e.target.closest('label')
    label.classList.add('errarum')
    setTimeout(_=>{label.classList.remove('errarum')}, 2000)
    alert("Sum of the selection can't be more than 500") 
    }
  else
    pSum.textContent = total
  }
```

```css
label {
  display : block;
  cursor  : pointer;
  }
.errarum {
  color  : red;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-forn">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb1" value="120" >
    Serial# 123001 (value = 120)
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb2" value="200" >
    Serial# 123002 (value = 200)
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb3" value="350" >
    Serial# 123003 (value = 350)
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ckb4" value="100" >
    Serial# 123004 (value = 100)
  </label>
</form>

<p id="p-sum"> Sum : <span>0</span><p>
```